# How to default the students to themselves if length of response of getStudents is 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, dropdown

I have a form with lists of subjects and students 
what am trying to do is if this subject has only 1 student to resit exam then set that student as default automatically (currently you have to select it from option as you would if the result is 2 or 3).
As am knew to react I just have the theory aspect, any one done this before?

EDIT:-
here is my code.

```
let studentOptions = this.state.selectedSubject
  ? this.state.selectedSubject._Student.map(student => {
    return {
      value: student._id,
      label: student.Name
    }
  })
```

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: Post your students and subjects array.

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi added the code am thinking to modify

Answer (score 1):

You can you componentDidMount lifecycle to check the getStudents length then set the state for the student based on the result.
You can read more about lifecycle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)